# TypeError: Cannot read property 'disabled' of null in react-testing-library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am using react testing library to test my login pages.

I was done with the testing of **should all fields must be empty initially**

The next thing was i need to check when someone type a wrong email it shows an error **Email is invalid** which will gives me an error and does not work properly

App.js

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import validator from 'validator'

function App() {

  const [error, setError] = useState("")
  const [signupInputs, setSignupInputs] = useState({
    email: "",
    password: "",
    confirmPassword: ""
  })

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    
    setSignupInputs({
      ...signupInputs,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    })
  }

  const handleClick =  (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // setError("")
    if(!validator.isEmail(signupInputs.email)){
      return setError("Email is invalid")
    }else if(signupInputs.password.length < 6){
      return setError("Password should have 6 or more chacraters")
    }else if(signupInputs.password !== signupInputs.confirmPassword){
      return setError("Password do not match")
    }
  };  
  return (
    <div className='container my-5'>
      <form>
        <div className='mb-3'>
          <label htmlFor='email' className='form-label'>Email Address</label>
          <input type="email" id="email" name="email" className='form-control' value={signupInputs.email} onChange={handleChange}/>
        </div>
        <div className='mb-3'>
          <label htmlFor='password' className='form-label'>Password</label>
          <input type="password" id="password" name="password" className='form-control' value={signupInputs.password} onChange={handleChange}/>
        </div>
        <div className='mb-3'>
          <label htmlFor='confirm-password' className='form-label'>Confirm Password</label>
          <input type="password" id="confirm-password" name="confirmPassword" className='form-control' value={signupInputs.confirmPassword} onChange={handleChange}/>
        </div>
        {error && <p className='text-danger'>{error}</p>}
        <button type='submit' className='btn btn-primary' onClick={handleClick}>Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And here is App.test.js

```
test("Should display error message on invalid email", () => {
  render(<App/>)
  const emailInputElement = screen.queryByText("textbox", {
    name: /email/i
  });

  const emailErrorElement = screen.queryByText(/Email is invalid/i) 
  
  const submitBtnElement = screen.getByRole("button",{
    name: /submit/i
  })
 
  expect(emailErrorElement).not.toBeInTheDocument()
  userEvent.type(emailInputElement,"johndoegmail.com")
  userEvent.click(submitBtnElement)
  const emailErrorElementAgain = screen.queryByText(/Email is invalid/i) 
  expect(emailErrorElementAgain).toBeInTheDocument()
})
```

The error I got

```
console.error
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'disabled' of null
        at typeImplementation (C:\Users\Desktop\car\node_modules\@testing-library\user-event\dist\type\typeImplementation.js:23:15)
        at Object.type (C:\Users\Desktop\car\node_modules\@testing-library\user-event\dist\type\index.js:27:60)
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Desktop\car\src\App.test.js:52:13)
        at Promise.then.completed (C:\Users\Desktop\car\node_modules\jest-circus\build\utils.js:391:28)
        at new Promise (<anonymous>)
        at callAsyncCircusFn (C:\Users\Desktop\car\node_modules\jest-circus\build\utils.js:316:10)
        at _callCircusTest (C:\Users\Desktop\car\node_modules\jest-circus\build\run.js:218:40)
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
        at _runTest (C:\Users\Desktop\car\node_modules\jest-circus\build\run.js:155:3)
        at _runTestsForDescribeBlock (C:\Users\Desktop\car\node_modules\jest-circus\build\run.js:66:9)
        at run (C:\Users\Desktop\car\node_modules\jest-circus\build\run.js:25:3)
        at runAndTransformResultsToJestFormat (C:\Users\Desktop\car\node_modules\jest-circus\build\legacy-code-todo-rewrite\jestAdapterInit.js:170:21)
        at jestAdapter (C:\Users\Desktop\car\node_modules\jest-circus\build\legacy-code-todo-rewrite\jestAdapter.js:82:19)
        at runTestInternal (C:\Users\Desktop\car\node_modules\jest-runner\build\runTest.js:389:16)
        at runTest (C:\Users\Desktop\car\node_modules\jest-runner\build\runTest.js:475:34)
        at Object.worker (C:\Users\Desktop\car\node_modules\jest-runner\build\testWorker.js:133:12)
```

Please if you find any mistake please let me know

Thanks

Comment: Can you add your validator code?

Comment: @LuisPauloPinto I used validator npm package

Answer (score 1):

First of all, not related to the error:

When you are using `screen` queries, you can skip container argument as the `testing-library` api docs says [here](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/bytext) (`ByText` example). So your `queryByText` could be:

```js
const emailInputElement = screen.queryByText(/email/i);

// Here, you already skip it
const emailErrorElement = screen.queryByText(/Email is invalid/i);
```

Related to the error, you are getting it because user-event `type` and `click` returns a promise and you can check `type` info [here](https://testing-library.com/docs/user-event/utility#type) and `click` [info](https://testing-library.com/docs/user-event/convenience/#clicks) here.

So, to fix this you just need to turn your test `async` and add an `await` to the user events:

```js
test("Should display error message on invalid email", async () => {
  render(<App />);

  const emailInputElement = screen.queryByText(/email/i);

  const emailErrorElement = screen.queryByText(/Email is invalid/i);

  const submitBtnElement = screen.getByRole("button", {
    name: /submit/i
  });

  expect(emailErrorElement).not.toBeInTheDocument();

  await userEvent.type(emailInputElement, "johndoegmail.com");
  await userEvent.click(submitBtnElement);

  const emailErrorElementAgain = screen.queryByText(/Email is invalid/i);

  expect(emailErrorElementAgain).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Comment: But the error remain same

Comment: I did a code sample and the test pass successfully. take a look [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-userevent-test-3h6psu?file=/src/App.test.js).

Comment: @LuisPauloPinto it seems the above solution doesn't work. I tried but facing the same issue